# Does Landscape support Ubuntu derivatives?

Tags: landscape, derivatives

Can we add an Ubuntu derivative to list of computers to manage in [Ubuntu Landscape](http://www.ubuntu.com/management) or just Ubuntu?

At least the official ones (Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about support in the commercial sense (as in - will you get paid support from Canonical with them), but landscape technically works fine on derivatives.
I personally run Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu and all of them work properly.

Full disclaimer: I'm a Landscape engineer.

Comment: I rephrased my question so it makes more sense. I hope.

Comment: So the answer to your rephrased question is "yes" :)

Comment: You can even get more exotic than the those derivatives - I regularly use it with Linaro.